# Speeding up Counting

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If you were to look at this page: http://www.storeboard.com/directory/california/sanfrancisco/ you would discover a page that is practically inaccessible because it can take over 30 secs to load.  Reason being is that there is a counter that counts the number of business members in each category.  I want to know if there is a way to speed up my existing script as now we have over a million members and the script in its current state is useless.  Here is my current script:

```
SELECT COUNT(MemberID) AS MembersInCountyCat
FROM Member
WHERE NYKACountyID = @NYKACountyID
AND (
        NYKACatID IN (
            SELECT NYKACatID
            FROM NYKACat
            WHERE ParentID = @NYKACatID
        )
        OR
        NYKACatID = @NYKACatID
    )
AND ProfileTypeID <> 1
```

Any advice as to how I can speed the sql script up would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,

neojakey

Comment: Please provide example data and desired results so we don't have to reverse engineer the requirement from your query.

Comment: Do you have indices on `MYKACountyID`, `NYKACatID`, `ParentID` and `ProfileTypeID` ? Those would be the most likely candidate for benefiting from an index to speed things up... also: what **version** of SQL Server are you using? Depending on how many rows match (or are excluded) by the `ProfileTypeID <> 1` clause, a **filtered** index (available in **2008** and newer) might be beneficial

Comment: Do the #s have to be real-time?

Comment: In cases like this I have used a cache table to keep a copy of the summary statistics.  Depending on the frequency of use and expense of recalculating, either a scheduled job refreshes the cache or the first user who hits the cache after it goes stale has to wait while it refreshes.  This has generally occurred when data has to be retrieved form an external data source, e.g. eBay.  Hopefully the suggestions re: indexes and triggers are more applicable to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(MemberId) AS MembersInCountyCat
FROM Member
    INNER JOIN NYKACat ON Member.NYKACatId = NYKACat.NYKACatId 
WHERE NYKACountyId = @NYKACountyId
    AND (NYKACat.NYKACatId = @NYKACatId OR NYKACat.ParentId = @NYKACatId)
    AND ProfileTypeId <> 1
```

Ensure you've got an index on ProfileTypeID, Member.NYKACountyId and Member.NYKACatId.

Comment: How do I check if there is an index..? and if there isn't one, how do I create one?

Comment: I changed the sql script to what you put and created a new index contain the fields you suggested.. and works great..  Can't thank you enough..

Answer (score 1):

Please give this a try.  Moving the NYKACat condidtions into the join may help it and I don't think it can hurt it.   If NYKACat.ParentID = @NYKACatID or NYKACat.NYKACatID = @NYKACatID eliminates most of the rows from NYKACat then it can do that up front.

with (nolock) allows dirty read
if you can't accept dirty reads then take it off

```
SELECT COUNT(Member.MemberID) AS MembersInCountyCat
FROM  Member  with (nolock) 
JOIN  NYKACat with (nolock)
  on  NYKACat.NYKACatID = Member.NYKACatID
 and (NYKACat.ParentID = @NYKACatID or NYKACat.NYKACatID = @NYKACatID)
WHERE Member.NYKACountyID = @NYKACountyID
  and Member.rofileTypeID <> 1
```